# iOS Ad-Hoc Distribution: Can't sign provisioning profile with distribution certificate in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am trying to perform an ad-hoc deployment of my iOS app. I cannot use automatically managed provisioning profiles. So I have manually created an iOS Distribution provisioning profile at developer.apple.com and signed it with an associated Distribution Certificate.

The problem is Xcode only lets me sign the distribution provisioning profile with a developer certificate:

[image]

developer.apple.com does not let you create a distribution provisioning profile with a developer certificate, so I don't know why Xcode does not let you sign with that same certificate. I have both development and distribution certificates valid (and they are not expired).

How do I get Xcode to accept my distribution certificate as a signing certificate for the iOS Distribution provisioning profile?

Comment: try with automatic sign in

Comment: Automatically managed profiles are not distribution profiles. I need to create it manually

Comment: Do you have an enterprise program membership?

Comment: Yes, which is how I was able to create the Distribution profile/certificate

Comment: You don't seem to have generated your provisioning profile correctly; it doesn't have a signing certificate associated with it.  Is your signing certificate visible in your Mac's "login" keychain?

Comment: you can distribute it as an ad-hoc and app store app with automatically sign in certificate

Comment: When I try is automatically managed profiles, I get an error during archiving that it can't find a provision profile for my bundle identifier.

Comment: And it does have a signing certificate associated with it, but it needs to be a Distribution certificate as per Apple's process for creating the profile (developer certificates are not listed as an option). Xcode does not allow me to sign with that distribution certificate

Comment: Xcode will let you sign with a distribution certificate, but that certificate needs to be present on the Mac you are using.  Are you using the mac that you used to generate the CSR?

Comment: Yes, the certificate shows up in Keychain Access and the Apple Developer Portal, but still Xcode is defaulting to the developer one and won’t let me pick

Comment: Does the certificate in the keychain have a private key associated with it?  If not, it is not usable for code signing.

Comment: Yes, it’s a private key in the Keychain

Comment: I'm having the same error. I DID create my Distribution certificate, I DID create my AD HOC provisioning profile, but it keeps telling me the same: that my AD HOC provisioning is missing y Developer certificate, which is wrong, since I explicitly created it for distribution. Also, when I try automatic signing, it works well, but it doesn't update the device list when I add a new device.

Comment: This has been properly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54738040/1311354)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First Both your certificates and Provisioning Profile should be of Ad-hoc Distribution type.
- Make sure you are using same certificate requested by your system (Request a Certificate from Certificate Authority, we do from keychain)