# Xcode signing release complaining about development certificate

Tags: xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

Straight to the point. Is this normal?

[image: Xcode settings]

As you can see, this is the release section of the signing. I'm choosing a distribution provisioning profile, yet it's complaining about the profile missing a development certificate! I was expecting "*iPhone Distribution*" instead of "*iPhone Developer*".

Also, it's listing the development provisioning profile as eligible! Can this happen? I mean a provisioning profile eligible in the release signing?

Am I missing something so obvious here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I'm choosing a distribution provisioning profile

Well, don’t. That’s wrong. You use a *development* provisioning profile for *all* build and run, and archive, operations — regardless of whether you are running on simulator or device, regardless of what the build configuration is (release or debug).

Distribution profile is purely for distribution (e.g. re-signing when exporting an archive up to the App Store).

Also, you should use automatic signing throughout the process; it knows more than you do (I say that in a nonpersonal way; it knows more than I do too!)

So, to sum up:

- Use automatic signing.
- Even if you use manual signing, use the development profile for *everything* in the interface you showed in your screen shot.

This is what the configuration for automatic signing looks like:

[image]

Here is how it configures your actual settings:

[image]

Notice that it uses the developer certificate, not the distribution certificate, for *all* configurations. If you must use manual signing, that is what you want to do too.

You won't need the distribution profile until a much later step in the process, when you export from an existing archive in the Organizer window, and at that point you'll be using a completely different interface. You can use automatic signing there too (though you don't have to).

Comment: And why  not use automatic signing? Xcode knows much more about this than you do.

Comment: I was fixing this issue to publish the app. So, I needed that.
Also, didn't know that automatically managing the certificates would work fine for distribution as well.

Comment: Ah. Gotcha. Thanks. Didn't like _You're not listening_ part though. But thanks :)

Comment: Well now that I've got you to read my answer more carefully I'll be glad to delete that comment! :)

Comment: @matt I'm in the same truoble. If I got you right I should then register tester's device UUIDs under my Developer Provisioning Profile, not under my Distribution. The first time i exported the  .ipa that way dough my testers couldn't use it. And under profile info I couldn't see any devices listed..that's why I got into this manually signing mess..

Comment: @Vincenzo I didn’t say anything like that. My answer is about how to archive, not how to export from the archive.

Comment: @Vincenzo There's only one way to make an archive: Product > Archive. My answer explains how to do that. There are lots of ways to export from the archive (in the Organizer window); for app store, for Ad Hoc, as file, etc. My answer doesn't talk about any of them. I know how to do them, but that's not what _this_ question and answer is about. No matter what you intend to do with the archive _later_, the archive is always created in just _one_ way.

Comment: @Matt Oh I see where my confusion is. So, archive has to be done with the Developer profile and not with the Distrubution. In the second phase ( exporting the .ipa with adHoc method ) if I still select automatic signin Xcode will switch to the distibution profile ( that is adHoc and contains the testers UUIDs ). Did I get it right this time? Sorry to bother so much

Comment: Yes, exactly right. If that _doesn't_ work for some reason, you can make a manual distribution profile with the testers UUIDs embedded and choose that explicitly as you export. Otherwise you'll just get all known device UUIDs. I should also say that nowadays I like TestFlight distribution a _lot_ more than Ad Hoc.

Comment: @matt  I've bee struggling with this as I'm trying to use Firebase App Distribution, for which I've been told that automatic signing doesn't work properly when exporting an ad-hod .ipa (not sure how would that be possible given that the export is done in Xcode and it doesn't  know what you're gonna do with it..) and so using manual signing would solve it. The real problem was that at the time I didn't have an Distribution ad-hoc profile with my testers Device UUID in it, but I added the to my Developer profile, so when using ad-hoc export Xcode just didn't find any ad-hoc profile to use.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using manual signing, go to build settings under your app's target.

- Under "Signing > Code Signing Identity > Release": Choose your specific production certificate from Keychain.
- Under "Signing > Development Team > Release": Choose your team.
- Under "Signing > Provisioning Profile > Release": Choose the appropriate distribution profile that is associated with the distribution certificate specified before.

This setup resolved the issue for me

Comment: Very thank you. Solved the issue for me :)

Answer (score 0):

It is normal. Did you created a production certificate? And did you sign the production provision-profile with it?
By the way - you can let xcode manage this for you.

Comment: Yes I created a production certificate (in fact, I have 3). And yes, I have a production provisioning profile signed with the certificate. However, xcode is asking for a provisioning profile signed with a development certificate. This is what causing confusion here.

Does letting xcode managing this work when publishing the app as well?

Comment: Yes, letting xcode manage this for you works well for publishing the app.

Comment: Another thing worth trying - delete your provision profiles and download them again.