# error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

> error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the
>   parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings
>   match the parent app's.
>
> ```
>   Embedded Binary Signing Certificate:    iPhone Developer: vincenzo
> ```
>
> calia (4DKTZT267L)        Parent App Signing Certificate:     iPhone
>   Distribution: vincenzo calia (M6933VXN9H)

I'm to try and use Firebase App Distribution for quick testing, but it appears that if you archive the app for an adHoc export mode, automatic signing messes things up and doesn't get used the distribution profile..so I'm trying to set to manual both certificate and Provisioning Profile to have the Developer certificate and profile with only my device UUIDs in it, and the distribution certificate and profile with tester's device UUIDs in it.
In my `Code Signing Identity` options I can choose a certificate I have 2 general `iOS Developer` and `iOS Distribution` under Automatic`certificates, and two specific`iPhone Developer: vincenzo calia (4DKTZT267L), and `iPhone Distribution: vincenzo calia (M6933VXN9H)` under `Identities in Keychain`.

No matter what combination I use I always get the error above while archiving.

I obviously didn't understand fully all the certificate/Profile thing..

Searching for the error I saw that I should use the same Certificate for both, `Debug` and `Release`, right?
But in Target/General/Signing/Debug if I switch Profile to use the Distribution one I get the error

> Provisioning profile "fixit cb dist profile" doesn't include signing
>   certificate "iPhone Developer: vincenzo calia (4DKTZT267L)".

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?
I read quite a few posts but I'm stuck on this one

Thank you very much

[image: certificate choice]

[image: Certificate chosen]

[image: target general]

[image]

Comment: I have seen it but didn't help me..but I found another that explained the problem in a clearer way..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54735615/xcode-signing-release-complaining-about-development-certificate this one..but still I don't understand why creating a Distrbution Certificatr and Profile if than I have to use the Developer anyway.

Comment: But registering my testers UUIDs under my Developer and then archive with an adHoc export system complains because that doesn't include adHoc..

Comment: Why is debug and release different?

Comment: It seems I misunderstood a few things.. i set the Release with my Distribution profile because there is where I added my testers device UUIDs. Hiw should I do this instead??

Comment: I suggest you clear the code signing settings, check the 'Automatically manage signing`, then select Team, which is what I often do, I hope to be useful to you.

Comment: It looks like I confused two phases: Archive and Export.
When archiving using automatic signing will be the best option.
When exporting, also using automatic signing will use the appropriate profile (ad-hoc in my case, which contains testers Device UUIDs)..
I didn't have and ad-hoc profile when trying the first time but had testers Device UUIDs under my Developer profile..so using ad-hoc export resulted in a no working .ipa..

Comment: Yes, whether you want `Archive` or `Export`, `Automatically manage signing` is working.